# I have a problem in understanding the picture given below

Tags: electric-current

[image: is in this circuit battery ,resistor and cell connected parallel][ what does the highlated part signify,is the wire connected with resistor in parallel, or it is directly connected with resistor or it is open.]

Answer (score 0):

It's a variable resistor.  So, it's like having 2 resistors connected to each other, R1 and R2, whereby their respective resistances are changed but the total is fixed R1+R2 = (Fixed value).

Comment: I did not understand,could you elaborate your answer

Comment: replace the long resistor with 2 resistors, R1 and R2.  R1 is placed on the left, and is connected to Positive side of the battery and to R2.  R2 is placed on the right is connected to the negative side of the battery and R1.   The current from the wire that appears disconnected from anything is attached to where R1 and R2 are connected.  R1 and R2 will change their values as some knob is turned.

Comment: Perhaps one of the most poorly drawn potentiometers I’ve ever seen…

Comment: @Dimple Functionally this means that the voltage difference between the cathode and anode can be set to any value between $0$ and $E_{ext}$ by adjusting the position of the "tap" on the potentiometer (typically done by rotating a knob).